# java Decryption logic: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption

Below is the code im using for Decryption.

```
 public String decrypt(String strToBeDecrypted) {
    try {
        if((strToBeDecrypted.trim().length()!=0) && !(strToBeDecrypted.trim().equals("")) && !(strToBeDecrypted.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))){
        strToBeDecrypted = URLDecoder.decode(strToBeDecrypted, "UTF-8");
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey skey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);

        byte[] keyByteArray = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(strToBeDecrypted);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(keyByteArray);

        return new String(original, "UTF-8");
    }
   }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(ExceptionUtil.getDetailedMessage(e));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Im getting "Unknown exception details: name=javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;message=Given final block not properly padded;" at the below line

```
 byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(keyByteArray);
```

Can anyone pls tell me what is the problem here? Im using the following keys

encryptkey=QvgC9vBXDZyM7RoAxevpHaawEbL5CW8Sp1zjEQ

iterations=19

segments=5

Comment: I don't see your key derivation anywhere. What does `iterations` and `segments` refer to? How is your `Cipher` instance created?

Comment: cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); @owlstead